# Movie with 2 female demons or monsters sucking nutrients from their victims through a plastic tube

Tags: horror, story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie that I watched ages ago when I was a child. I don't remember the name but I only remember there are 2 female demons or monsters. They suck the nutrients of the victims from a thing looks like a plastic tube. In the end they being sealed and conjoined together in an egg shaped like statue. I spent too much time looking for this movie, thanks so much if anyone can tell me the name.

Answer (score 4):

Clive Barker's "Saint Sinner"(2002 TV movie)?

Here is the plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Sinner_(film)).

> In 1815 California, Father Michael, an emissary of Pope Pius VII, has traveled to meet with novice monk Brother Tomas. The young monk's order serves as the secret repository for evil, supernatural objects collected by the Church, and kept there for safekeeping. Michael delivers an ancient statue that has trapped two beautiful female demons, Munkar and Nakir. Tomas and his friend Brother Gregory inadvertently release the murderous demons, who travel to the 21st century using the monastery's Wheel of Time.
>
> As his brother lies dying, he is given a chance to redeem himself by going through the Wheel of Time with a sacred dagger previously used by Saint Nicodemus to imprison the succubi. Tomas reluctantly intends to track down the evil creatures and destroy them. The young monk takes on the task, traveling through the Wheel only to discover a future world he does not understand in present-day Seattle, Washington, where he allies with police detective Rachel Dressler to recapture the homicidal terrors.
>
> While the creatures seek to satisfy their centuries-long hunger, Tomas discovers their first victim. The police arrive on the murder scene and take Tomas into custody, believing he may be involved. Detective Rachel Dressler (Ravera) isn't about to believe Tomas' weird story, but strange things start to happen and bodies begin to pile up. Both Tomas and Rachel soon discover that the only way to stop these horrifying demons will be to take a leap of faith.

Below is the official trailer: